# Syntax error, space in the username command

Tags: syntax, centos, command, space

I'm trying to change the owner and the group of a directory and any subdirectories and archives in a centos sytem
I'm using this commands:

```
chown -R mc4380 [502] /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
chgrp -R mc4380 [502] /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
```

The way to directory is:
/home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
And the new owner and group are:
mc4380 [502]
The problem is the space in the mc4380 [502], I receive this error when I execute the command:
chown: cannot access `[502]': No such file or directory
I Already tried this and don't worked:

```
chown -R "mc4380 [502]" /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
chown -R 'mc4380 [502]' /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
chown -R mc4380\ [502] /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
```

everytime receiving this:
chown: invalid user: `mc4380 [502]'
But the user/group exists and are okay, and when i used this command:

```
chown   -R    new_owner:new_group     /directory
```

Him understood the first argument changing successful the owner of the archives/directory and subdirectorys

Oh, sorry my bad english, I tried to do my best

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
chown -R mc4380\ \[502\] /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server4380
```